# MySQL query to match unquoted strings

Tags: mysql, regex

I need to get all the records that contain `cooking spray`, but only if it is not in quotes:

```
cooking spray    > 1
'cooking spray'  > 0
"cooking spray"  > 0
```

I'm just having trouble working out the REGEXP.  This seems close, but I'm getting a message that says "repetition-operator operand invalid".

```
select count(*)
from recipes r 
where r.ingredient REGEXP '(?<![\'"])cooking spray(?![\'"])'
```

Comment: Do you want `cooking sprayx` to count as a match?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `REGEXP` value instead:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM recipes r 
WHERE r.ingredient REGEXP '(^|[^\'"])cooking spray([^\'"]|$)'
```

**EDIT:**
Following [Patrick Q comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811246/mysql-query-to-match-unquoted-strings/24811495?noredirect=1#comment38514551_24811495), I edited the regex to match :

- `cooking spray`
- `foo cooking spray`
- `cooking spray bar`
- `foo cooking spray bar`

Comment: mmmm... Won't that require some non-quote character before `cooking` and also match a non-quote character after `spray` if one appears?

Comment: @PatrickQ You can add `?` (optional effect), pretty sure it would work.

Comment: Ow ok ! GeriBoss' comment made me understant. You're totally right, I'll correct it.

Comment: What you have will not match `cooking spray` (but OP wants it to), but will match `cooking sprayx` (which OP probably does not want it to).

Answer (score 0):

How about just using `like`?

```
select count(*)
from recipes r
where r.ingredient like '%cooking spray%' and
      r.ingredient not like '%''cooking spray''%' and
      r.ingredient not like '%"cooking spray""%';
```

I realize that none of these solution will work if the ingredient contains both the quoted and unquoted forms.  For this, use `replace`:

```
select count(*)
from recipes r
where replade(replace(r.ingredient, '''cooking spray''', ''), '"cooking spray"', '') like '%cooking spray%'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (doesn't use lookarounds): `'.*[^"\']cooking spray[^"\'].*'`

(PS: **zessx** was faster, and his answer handles edge-cases better)